# Getting Upload progress with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am having trouble getting the progress of a file upload using PHP, the server that my site is hosted on is using php v5.6.

I also have the 'uploadprogress' setting enabled in my cpanel manager.

I tried to follow this tutorial:
[Tracking Upload Progress with PHP and JavaScript](https://www.sitepoint.com/tracking-upload-progress-with-php-and-javascript/)

But I merged it with some other code that handles uploading of files using an ajax request.

My form code:

```
    <form id="myForm">
        <input type="hidden" value="myForm" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>">
        <input type="file" id="file" />
        <a href="javascript:uploadFile()">Upload</a>
    </form>
    Upload:
    <div id="process">0%</div>
```

Javascript code:
    var timer;

```
function uploadFile() {
    var uploadFile = $("#file")[0].files[0];
    timer = setInterval(getStatus,1000);

    $.ajax( 
        {
            url : "upload.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data : new FormData($('form')[0]),
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,

            xhr: function() {
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if (myXhr.upload) {
                    // For handling the progress of the upload
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',
                        function(e) {
                            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                                if (e.loaded < e.total) {
                                    $('#process').html(((e.loaded / e.total) * 100).toFixed(1) + "%");
                                } else {
                                    $('#process').html("Processing upload, please wait.");
                                }
                            }
                        } , false);
                }

                return myXhr;
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#process').html(response);
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }
        }
    );
}

function getStatus() {
    $.get("progress.php",
        function(response) {
            $("#process2").html(response);
        }
    );
}
```

upload.php

```
session_start();
$uploadedFile = $_FILES["file"];

move_uploaded_file($uploadedFile['tmp_name'],$uploadedFile["name"]);

echo $uploadedFile["name"]." was uploaded";
```

progress.php

```
session_start();

$key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") . "myForm";
if (!empty($_SESSION[$key])) {
    $current = $_SESSION[$key]["bytes_processed"];
    $total = $_SESSION[$key]["content_length"];
    echo $current < $total ? ceil($current / $total * 100) : 100;
}
else {
    echo 100;
}
```

Unfortunately in my JS the line:
    $('#process').html(((e.loaded / e.total) * 100).toFixed(1) + "%");

only gets the time it takes to get the request, not actually upload the file.

I hope I have provided enough information to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure your server is running PHP with mod_php.

I'm running Drupal on nginx and warns me that

"Your server is not capable of displaying file upload progress. File upload progress requires an Apache server running PHP with mod_php."